# Using inparaitem in a formal document

Tags: itemize

I have employed the following code sample in my master thesis:

```
Among others, SLAM has successfully been used in areas such as:
\begin{inparaitem}
\item Self-driving cars - Unmanned Ground Vehicles (UGV)
\item Unmanned aerial vehicles (UAV)
\item Underwater vehicles (UUV)
\item Planetary rovers
\item Domestic robots
\item Biomedical applications
\end{inparaitem}
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

When I showed it to a professor of mine he suggested that no inline bullet lists should exist in formal docs and I should rather use the standard `itemize` environment.

Even though I find the result rather elegant I haven't seen it in any papers or relevant work so far. Should this structure be avoided?

Comment: I do not think that this is a question that is suited for this site (pure opinion-based). Apart from that, I would not use this format unless I have a page number restriction or similar.

Comment: I wouldn't use a list at all if writing this in a formal context. For something like a handout or teaching materials, sure, but not in professional writing. In any case, your professor is the best judge of this in your context and for your discipline. Whatever anybody says here (or doesn't say here, since this is off-topic), what your professor says will trump it.

Answer (score 1):

As a normal reader,and as a part of my job now is to read scientific paper, I have never seen such representation.

Since you are listing, I guess your professor is right it's a lot more elegant and comforting for the reader to use the traditional `itemize`, and if your goal is to save space because the information are minors and not that important i suggest you to use `,`and`etc..`.

The inline bullets don't seems professional.